# DrupalGap Frontpage not displaying

Tags: services, javascript

I am following the drupalgap hello world creation tutorial, however all i tried to make the hello world proven to be unsucessful.

here is the frontpage config fron settings.js

i did the installation on mobile folder and the setting file is settings.js

```
// App Title
drupalgap.settings.title = 'gsam';

// App Front Page
drupalgap.settings.front = 'hello_world';
```

the module name is gsam with directory structure:

```
mobile/app/modules/custom/gsam
```

and here is my gsam.js,

when every i load my server pointing to the mobile I have 404, that is after i placed this code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function gsam_menu() {
  var items = {};
  items['hello_world'] = {
    title: 'DrupalGap',
    page_callback: 'gsam_hello_world_page'
  };
  return items;
}

/**
 * The callback for the "Hello World" page.
 */
function gsam_hello_world_page() {
  var content = {};
  content['my_button'] = {
    theme: 'button',
    text: 'Hello World',
    attributes: {
      onclick: "drupalgap_alert('Hi!')"
    }
  };
  return content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be the apparent failure to refer the your custom module in your project settings.js. This file resides in mobile/app/modules/custom/gsam/www/app. Edit the file and add the following code in the *custom module* section:

```
Drupal.modules.custom['gsam'] = {};

drupalgap.settings.front = 'hello_world';
```